# How to avoid printing exception and assign another action when exception was encountered? My attempt don't work right

Tags: java, exception

I am encountering an error when user doesn't type anything into input statement. I thought of using Try/Catch blocks to instead throw exception to set boolAskRepeat to true which should skip to the end of the code and repeat the loop.

This doesn't work, and I believe I'm missing something but I'm not sure what... It still throws exception saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at ITSLab03.main(ITSLab03.java:34)
```

Which is this line of code: `inputStatus = input.readLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
while (boolAskStatus == true)
{
    System.out.print("Employment Status (F or P): ");

    try 
    { 
        inputStatus = input.readLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0); 

        if (inputStatus == "f".charAt(0))
        {
            boolAskStatus = false;

            String stringCheckSalary = null;
            boolean boolCheckSalary = true;
            while (boolCheckSalary == true)
            {
                // some code
            }

            outputData(inputName, inputStatus, calculateFullTimePay(inputSalary));
        }
        else if (inputStatus == "p".charAt(0))
        {
            // some code                

            outputData(inputName, inputStatus, calculatePartTimePay(inputRate, inputHours));
        }
        else boolAskStatus = true;

    } 
    catch (IOException e) { boolAskStatus = true; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` as well (If you observe the stack trace properly this is the exception you are getting)

```
  catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            boolAskStatus = true;  
      }
```

(or) 
catch `Exception` which catches all runtime exceptions

```
catch (Exception e) {
                boolAskStatus = true;  
          }
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on exceptions on this case because the user not entering anything isn't really an exceptional case - it can happen routinely.  I'd split the line `inputStatus = input.readLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);` into two, the first of which would read the line: `inputStatus = input.readLine().toLowerCase()`.  Then check the length of the string and take action accordingly.

Comment: @JohnHawksley: I agree, but I have half knowledge on requirement, my answer is just how to overcome the issue OP having.

Comment: Yes of course - my comment was really a design issue, rather than answering the question :) But you're right, your solution does answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

The normal try catch pattern should look like this:

```
try
{
    // code that is vulnerable to crash
}
catch (Specific-Exception1 e1)
{
    // perform action pertaining to this exception
}    
catch (Specific-Exception2 e2)
{
    // perform action pertaining to this exception
}    
....
....
catch (Exception exp) // general exception, all exceptions will be caught
{
    // Handle general exceptions. Normally i would end the program or 
    // inform the user that something unexpected occurred.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `.charAt(0)`, you are assuming that the String has a length > 0.

You could simplify this a bunch by just doing:

```
String entry = input.readLine().toLowerCase();
if (entry.startsWith("f")) {
    ...
}
else if ("entry".startsWith("p")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 For a solution that doesn't depend on exception throwing/catching (Item 57 in _Effective Java 2nd Edition_)

Comment: I would assume that this solution would be better since try/catch is using more system resources. But I must use `char` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work the way you want because `input.readLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0)` throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which is not an `IOException`, so the catch block never gets hit. You can make it work by changing the catch to

```
catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsExceptione e) { boolAskStatus = true; }
```

But...

It's generally not a good idea to base your program's normal behaviour on exception handling. Think of exception throwing as something that could happen, but usually won't. Why not use something like:

```
final String STATUS_F = "f";
final String STATUS_P = "p";

String fromUser = null;
do {
    String rawInput = input.readLine().toLowerCase();
    if (rawInput.startsWith(STATUS_F)) {
        fromUser = STATUS_F;
    } else if (rawInput.startsWith(STATUS_P)) {
        fromUser = STATUS_P;
    }
} while (fromUser == null);

if (STATUS_F.equals(fromUser)) {
    // do something
} else if (STATUS_P.equals(fromUser)) {
    // do something else
} else {
    // Shouldn't be able to get here!
    throw new Exception("WTF!?");
}
```

It much easier for another person reading this to understand why the program loops and how the loop is controlled, in part because the code that figures out what the user is inputting and the code that decides what to do with that information are separated. Plus, you don't need to deal with exceptions.